# How to do clean reinstall?

Tags: miktex, installing

After updating with the package manager, I can't compile any more, because I get the error "amsmath.sty not found".

I'd like to do a complete new install of MiKTeX. I did an uninstall using Windows, but still had two directories of MiKTeX 2.9, so I tried to remove them.  Also have a directory for 2.8. I have files with extensions `.old.old` that I can't remove.  Should I remove everything?  And what to do about the `.old.old` files?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! There was recently a problem with  the `tools` package missing in MiKTeX distribution, which resulted in a mess. This problem is solved now. In my opinion you should simply try to update again.

Comment: And yes, you should remove everything, or at least rename it.